# Need help in section "take test" section

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the below route for test taking section.

```
Router.post('/exam', auth.checkLogin, function(req , res){ 

examModel.findOne({'exam_code' : req.body.exam_code} , function(err,doc1){ 

if(err) 
res.send("Some error occurred"); 
else if(doc1) 
{ 
responseModel.findOne({'exam_code': req.body.exam_code}, function(err,doc){ 

if(err) 
res.send("Some error occurred"); 
else if(doc) 
res.redirect('/exam'); 
else 
{ 
res.render('take_exam', { title: 'Take Exam', exam_code: req.body.exam_code, Username: req.body.Username}); 
} 
}) 
} 
else 
{ 
res.redirect('/exam'); 
} 

}) 
});

Below is the route for submitting test:

Router.post('/submit', auth.checkLogin, function(req , res){ 

var object = req.body; 
var response = []; 

for(var key in object) { 

response.push(object[key]); 
} 
response.pop(); 
response.pop(); 

var temp_response = new responseModel({ 

Username : req.body.Username, 
exam_code: req.body.exam_code, 
response : req.body.response 
}); 

temp_response.save(function(err , docs){ 

if(err) 
res.send("Some error occurred"); 
else 
res.render('exam_submit', {title: 'Response Submitted Successfully', response: req.body.response, Username: req.body.Username, exam_code: req.body.exam_code}); 
}); 
}); 

app.use('/take_exam',Router); 
}
```

When I click the start test button and enter the test taking page "I am presented with the test taking page" but the questions do not appear. Only the headings and the options A.B.C.&D appear.

I have included the required views.

Please have a look at it and suggest me what to do next?

Comment: Please share the front-end template and give us an example of what the data structure of the `Exam` and `Response` models is.

Comment: Example of Exam model:    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var examSchema = new Schema({
 exam_name :{type:String,default:'',required:true},
 exam_code :{type:String,default:'',required:true},
 duration_hours : {type:String,default:'',required:true},
 duration_minutes : {type:String,default:'',required:true}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Exam',examSchema);

Comment: The front end template is written in jade.

Comment: I meant to ask you to share your template code as well.

Comment: As the template code is too long hence I have uploaded the files to google drive.  Please download it from there. Link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BBJ_TP1U2cgrz4B9aHaxctyyyxnQRF9x.